# Calling methods from one ASP.Net web form from another web form

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, oop, webforms

A site I'm working on has two different pages, and each one is attempting to do the same thing. One of the pages, though still in use, has not been updated and so the code is no longer doing everything it is meant to do.

Rather than continue this wet solution and copy the missing code, I would like to make use of the code that has been updated. Ideally I would copy the function into a helper class or make a base class to provide this functionality, but the one function calls many private functions, and each of the private function mixes business logic with the presentation logic.

I have no documentation and a short time scale, so to do this would not be feasible. So my question is, what are the disadvantages of calling the function on page1.aspx from page2.aspx? It is a shared function so I'm hoping it will be OK but advice would be appreciated.

Comment: If it is calling private functions which contain both business and presentation logic specific to the page then how could you hope to use it?

Comment: I don't understand your point? I call the method and it fires. What I'm interested in is why I would want to avoid doing this.

Comment: My point is exactly the same as JohnSaunders. If it is truly shared then you can pull it out into it's own helper class.  If it isn't and it is referring to fields or objects in the owning page then it isn't shared and you really shouldn't be calling it.  But without code no one here will be able to say yes or no. But from what you've provided: No.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a bloody mess to me. You are not to descript but without really seeing whats going on it is hard to say. If this code is touching dom elements and hitting page cycle events it will probably be a pain. I would say.. take the actual business logic and put it in another class outside of the page and then reference the business logic that way but for dom elements directly webforms is already over complicated I would try staying away from making it worse. Perhaps you can pull these dom elements into a user control and reuse it on both pages? Either way sounds like you have plenty of fun a head of you :)

Answer (score 1):

It would be best if you showed some of the code, but I have to say that if the two methods are `Shared`, then you're probably ok.

However, such `Shared` code doesn't belong on *either* page. It belongs in some other class that can be accessed by both pages.

Comment: Thanks, i know a seperate class is the way to go i was looking for quick options. Im primarily concerned with testing as without docs i will struggle.

Comment: How long does it take to just move the code to a separate class?